# tsconfig paths in worker_threads

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, worker-thread, node-worker-threads

I'm spinning up some node workers and need each worker to pull code from a path expressed in tsconfig's paths compiler options.  How do you configure worker to acknowledge paths from tsconfig?

here's how I create a Worker:

```
const workerTs = (ordinalPosition: number, file: string, workerOptions: WorkerOptions): Worker =>
{
  workerOptions.eval = true;

  if (!workerOptions.workerData)
  {
    workerOptions.workerData = {};
  }

  workerOptions.workerData.__filename = file;
  workerOptions.workerData.blsSalaryArray = blsSalaryArray;
  workerOptions.workerData.dataToProcess = chunks[ ordinalPosition ];

  return new Worker(`
    const wk = require('worker_threads');
    require('ts-node').register();
    let file = wk.workerData.__filename;
    delete wk.workerData.__filename;
    require(file);`,
    workerOptions
  );
};
```

And here's the error I'm receiving:

```
{
  diagnosticText: "... Cannot find module '@datastop-io/datastop-io-libraries' or its corresponding type declarations.\r\n",
  diagnosticCodes: [ 2307 ]
}
```

Here's my paths configuration in tsconfig.base.json:

```
{
   "compilerOptions":
    {
       "paths":
       {
"@datastop-io/datastop-io-libraries":["libs/datastop-io-libraries/src/index.ts"]
       }
    }
}
```